# camel netty4http and camel rest dsl: Get remote address

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I'm looking for a way to get the ip address with camel rest dsl and the Netty4 Http component.

I checked on the documentation, I've put a breakpoint on my rest and checked on the headers, the properties,...everywhere, and couldn't find a proper way get this information.

Headers log:

GET: http://localhost:8080/category, 
{Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch, Accept-Language=fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4, breadcrumbId=ID-nateriver-54582-1445489005229-0-1, CamelCATEGORY_ACTION=listAction, CamelHttpMethod=GET, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpUri=/category, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8080/category, CamelJmsDeliveryMode=2, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=0, Cookie=JSESSIONID=fowfzar8n09e16ej9jui6nmsv, Host=localhost:8080, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=topic://Statistics, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:nateriver-54592-1445489009836-3:1:7:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1445489017233, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36}

Comment: Did you really check the headers?  I use netty and the client is visible in the headers.

Comment: I did. I am using Camel rest dsl and netty4 http component (not just netty).
I checked on the headers, (no ip address from the client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get two headers populated:

CamelNettyLocalAddress and CamelNettyRemoteAddress.

See here where the debug log of netty-http shows this clearly.
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-create-case-insensitive-URI-route-with-netty4-http-td5766517.html#a5766558